# The mean of the following expression:

Tags: means

> Suppose a discrete random variable X takes on the values $0, 1, 2, ,n$
>   with frequencies proportional to binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{0},
> \binom{n}{1},....,\binom{n}{n}$ Then the mean (m ) and the variance
>   ($s_{2}$ ) of the distribution are?

I differentiated the binominal expansion and took $x=1$ which concluded to 
$\sum x_{i}= n2^{n-1}$ .Therefore the **mean** should be $ \frac{\sum x_{i}}{n}=2^{n-1} $.
But, the mean is  $\frac{n}{2}$.

Can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't sum up the number of values... you sum up the *frequencies* of those values.  Remember that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n$ as per the binomial theorem.  Regardless, this is a binomial distribution where $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$.  The mean is $np$ and the variance is $npq$

Comment: OH! Got it , Many thanks friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total frequency isn't $n$. In fact, it's proportional to

$$\sum_{i = 0}^n {n\choose i} = 2^n$$

hence the mean should be

$$\frac{n\cdot 2^{n - 1}}{2^n} = \frac{n}{2}$$

Comment: Silly mistake, Many thanks!

Comment: @MAthsjunky No problem. It does happen to all of us occasionally :)